# Login Using Curl on joomla website

Tags: joomla

I can't get php curl login to joomla site. i don't have any access to this site
Following is the similar code i have used. it is https site. it is giving me object has been moved here.

```
<?php
$uname = $_POST['username'];
$upswd = $_POST['password'];
$url = "https://www.mytestjoomla.com/index.php?option=com_user&view=login";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath('./cookie.txt'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath('./cookie.txt'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE );
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
if (!preg_match('/name="([a-zA-z0-9]{32})"/', $ret, $spoof)) {
    preg_match("/name='([a-zA-z0-9]{32})'/", $ret, $spoof);
}

// POST fields
$postfields = array();
$postfields['username'] = urlencode($uname);
$postfields['passwd'] = urlencode($upswd);
$postfields['option'] = 'com_user';
$postfields['task'] = 'login';
$postfields[$spoof[1]] = '1';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
echo $ret = curl_exec($ch);

// Get logged in cookie and pass it to the browser
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: (.*?);/m', $ret, $m);
$cookie=explode('=',$m[1]);
setcookie($cookie[0], $cookie[1]);
?>
```

Comment: first of all your $postfields['passwd'] is mistake it should be $postfields['password'] and wht error you will get ?

Comment: @PratikPrajapati If the server is not allowing you to access the data through CURL then why ur trying to do it so ?